# Passing parameter to a callback which is passed as parameter

Tags: javascript

In the following code:

```
makeComponent: function(componentBuilder, myLib) {
  componentBuilder.build(function(cmpDefinition, status){
    if (status === 'OK') {
      myLib.doSomething(cmpDefinition);
    }
  });
}
```

I want to put the inner callback function in a separate function:

```
callBackFunc: function(myLib) {
   return function(cmpDefinition, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          myLib.doSomething(cmpDefinition);
        }
   }
}

makeComponent: function(componentBuilder, myLib) {
  var callBackFuncVar = callBackFunc(myLib);
  componentBuilder.build(callBackFuncVar(cmpDefinition, status));
}
```

This code doesn't work, I need to change `makeComponent` function to the following:

```
makeComponent: function(componentBuilder, myLib) {
  var callBackFuncVar = callBackFunc(myLib);
  componentBuilder.build(function(cmpDefinition, status) {
       callBackFuncVar(cmpDefinition, status)      
  });
}
```

Why directly calling `callBackFuncVar` and passing parameter to it, as mentioned, doesn't work ?

**Edited**

What if I do this:

```
callBackFunc: function(cmpDefinition, status) {
        var myLib = this.myLib;
        if (status === 'OK') {
          myLib.doSomething(cmpDefinition);
        }
   }

makeComponent: function(componentBuilder, myLib) {
  componentBuilder.build(callBackFunc.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing this:

```
callBackFunc: function(myLib) {
   return function(cmpDefinition, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          myLib.doSomething(cmpDefinition);
        }
   }
}

makeComponent: function(componentBuilder, myLib) {
  var callBackFuncVar = callBackFunc(myLib);
  componentBuilder.build(callBackFuncVar);
}
```

The reasoning behind this is that `componentBuilder.build` was receiving a function in the first example and the result of callBackFuncVar in the second one, instead of the callBackFuncVar function.

Comment: in a separate question, how can we pass parameters to `callBackFunc` ?

Comment: I do not fully understand if you mean the callBackFunc or the function which is returned by callBackFunc. Anyway, you should read about `call`, `apply` and `bind` methods in JavaScript. It might help you to understand the functional programming in JavaScript.

Comment: I meant the function returned by `callBackFunc`

Comment: Just like any other function. `callBackFuncVar(cmpDefinition, status)` would call the function with these arguments but, in your second example which is wrong, `componentBuilder.build` expects a function, not a function-call nor a the result of calling a function.

Comment: What if I replace the outter function `callBackFunc` with the inner function `function(cmpDefinition, status)` and `bind(this)` to the callback function in `makeComponent` ?

Comment: You cannot do that because the name `callBackFunc` is not defined in that snippet. You have `callBackFunc` as key of an object, but not as a name itself. If you want to do that, you have to create the `callBackFunc` outside the object.